# Issues with hero slick slider as it is not covering full width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using slick responsive slider from

```
/*
     _ _      _       _
 ___| (_) ___| | __  (_)___
/ __| | |/ __| |/ /  | / __|
\__ \ | | (__|   < _ | \__ \
|___/_|_|\___|_|\_(_)/ |___/
                   |__/

 Version: 1.5.5
  Author: Ken Wheeler
 Website: http://kenwheeler.github.io
    Docs: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick
    Repo: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick
  Issues: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues

 */
```

the website i am using on seems to have an issue with the website image not showing up properly

[Here](http://mikeyourcarguy.ca/index.cfm) is the website address.

the arrows on both sides showing different images start which looks weird i bigger screens

using the following as the js code

```
$('.slick-hero-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4500,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        mobileFirst:true,
        variableWidth: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve a full width slider background with the following CSS:

```
.slick-hero-slider .image-bg {
width: 100vw!important;
}
```

I hope this helps! :)